# x and y in a MotionEvent ACTION_UP is sometimes duplicate of an earlier ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, motionevent

Dear fellow stackoverflowers,

### Problem Description

I am working on a simple view for drawing using the inputs from onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent). To achieve this I use coordinates from ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP with one pointer.

In addition to each MotionEvent's x and y value, I am interested in the historical x's and y's to get as much data as possible. The problem is that quite often the x and y from the ACTION_UP event is identical to the previous ACTION_MOVE's last

### Problem Example

Let me illustrate with an example of 4 MotionEvents representing a user touching the screen, moving the finger a bit and then releasing the finger. In the example I use xHistory for the list of values available through getHistoricalX, and yHistory for the same with getHistoricalY.

**1. ACTION_DOWN:**

- xHistory = []
- yHistory = []
- x        = 5.0
- y        = 6.0

**2. ACTION_MOVE:**

- xHistory = [5.5, 5.8, 6.2]
- yHistory = [6.5, 6.8, 7.2]
- x        = 6.6
- y        = 7.6

**3. ACTION_MOVE:**

- xHistory = [7.0, 7.5, 8.0]
- yHistory = [7.7, 7.8, 8.0]
- x        = 8.5
- y        = 8.2

**4. ACTION_UP:**

- xHistory = []
- yHistory = []
- x        = 8.0
- y        = 8.0

As can be seen in the fourth event, the x and y of ACTION_UP is the same as the last index of xHistory and yHistory. This happens even though I am not moving my finger backwards. I would expect that the x and y of ACTION_UP are always the same as the x and y of the last ACTION_MOVE event (if there was any).

### Implementation

I use MotionEvent.getHistoricalX() and MotionEvent.getHistoricalY() combined with MotionEvent.x and MotionEvent.y to build lists of points in an extension property (kotlin) of MotionEvent.

In the implementation I create a list of points, where the points are represented by `FloatArray`s of size 2. I call the list that includes both the historical coordinates and the latest coordinate a `historyVector`.

```kotlin
val MotionEvent.historyVector: Array<FloatArray>
    get() {
        val historyVector = mutableListOf<FloatArray>()

        for (i in 0 until this.historySize) {
            historyVector.add(floatArrayOf(this.getHistoricalX(i), this.getHistoricalY(i)))
        }
        historyVector.add(floatArrayOf(this.x, this.y))

        return historyVector.toTypedArray()
    }
```

I use this historyVector for ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP, and sometimes the results are as expected and other times the results are like in the example in the section above.

Have any of you seen this behavior before? I assume there must be something I have misunderstood and/or something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using physical device or an emulator? I think I've been encountering this on emulators but not on real devices (flings failing or being reversed etc)

Comment: Physical device. A Nokia 4.2 running Android 10

Answer (score 0):

I never seen this behaviour before, however you could do one of these things:

- consider ACTION_UP at the latest ACTION_MOVE coords (an additional check could be checking milliseconds difference and assume latest Move's coords only when this diff is less than 100ms)
- when ACTION_UP happens you can "create/raise a fake" ACTION_MOVE event using UP's coords

Additionally you can also check for ACTION_UP.getEventTimeNano() and verify if this event is really occurred AFTER last ACTION_MOVE.getEventTimeNano(), and if it's not then discard its information and use only ACTION_MOVE data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am considering thinking of ACTION_UP as the end point of the stroke I am currently drawing and disregards its coordinates, but worried this might sometimes be wrong if there actually is some new data there